# jQuery eats my data in custom event for certain property names

Tags: jquery

When doing this:

```
$(document.body).on(
  'myevent',
  function (ev) {
    console.log(ev.data, ev.result);
  }
);

$(document.body).trigger(
  $.Event(
    'myevent',
    {
      data: 'foo',
      result: 'bar'    
    }
  )
);
```

The console returns `[null, undefined]`. It this something expected? I found it troubling since there is no original event to copy the properties from, and I am running out of property names to send out server response.

ref: http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

ref: http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/

Note of the documents describe this behavior. If some one knows why and explain from the jQuery source code it would be great; we could file a bug if it's something unexpected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `ev.data` property is the data passed in the `.on()` call, and there is nothing passed so it returns `null`. The data property you added in your call to `$.Event` is overwritten by the `null`. Don't use any property names mentioned here for your custom data name:
http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/

Comment: Can you find the actual line # in `jquery.js` that actually did this?

Answer (score 5):

how about

```
$(document).on('myevent',"body",function (ev,x) {
    console.log(x.data);
    console.log(x.result);   
  }
);
$(document.body).trigger('myevent',{data:'foo',result: 'bar'});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZbBAh/17/

Comment: Thanks (+1), I am fully aware there is a second argument for extra properties. I just don't like this way.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know who this might help but at least once I found myself with mixed code that looks like this:

```
... .trigger('myevent', $.Event('myevent', {data: 'foo',result: 'bar'}))'
```

i.e. both providing the event name as a parameter to .trigger and providing an event object with custom data ** the custom data**.

The code should be either

```
... .trigger($.Event('myevent', {data: 'foo',result: 'bar'}))'
```

or

```
... .trigger('myevent', {data: 'foo',result: 'bar'})'
```

of course they are not identical in where you get the data in you event handler but at least they both work...